# Authentication using email instead of username and without authorization in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to only use the the authentication part of spring security and use email instead of username with mysql. does anyone has a code for that?
or maybe without spring security how to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Without spring security that means that you will just check if user exists in the database with correct credentials, you can follow this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/registration-restful-api